# How to check whether particular port is open or closed on UNIX?

Tags: unix

I am very new to unix. How can I check that a particular port is free or used right now ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
netstat -ano|grep 443|grep LISTEN
```

will tell you whether a process is listening on port 443 (you might have to replace LISTEN with a string in your language, though, depending on your system settings).

Comment: note that after this call is made you can use $? to check if the grep matched... eg "echo $?" immediately after this will output 0 for the cases where the port was open and 1 for the case where the port wasn't open. you may find this value more usable as part of a larger script.

Comment: When I need a clean 0/1 output, I use this: `netstat -ano | grep ':443\s' | if grep -q LISTEN; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi`. Here, `:` and `\s` are for separating port numbers such as 443 and 4430, and -q is for keeping grep quiet

Comment: Note that at least in Debian bullseye this package is not installed as default.

Answer (score 22):

Try (maybe as root)

```
lsof -i -P
```

and grep the output for the port you are looking for.

For example to check for port 80 do

```
lsof -i -P | grep :80
```