# How to run xampp server when already Apache runing on 80 port?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, apache2

[image: Apache Web Server in not running]

And i have already changed port 80 to 81 but it is not working . when i stop the apache2 server previous one  than  it starts.

So problem is , How to run both at same time ?

Comment: Could you try a port higher than 1024, like 8080. It's possible your user doesn't have permission to bind to a privileged port.

Comment: no it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

You should to check if your port 81 is already used for another process. How to check a port?

Windows: [How to determine if a port is open on a Windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server)

Linux/Mac: [How to check whether particular port is open or closed on UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139309/how-to-check-whether-particular-port-is-open-or-closed-on-unix)